# Discord.js v12+ TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js, unhandled-promise-rejection

So I'm overwriting permissions for a ticket feature and its giving me an error

> Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

with this line of code:

```
    message.guild.channels.create(`create-${message.author.id}`, { type: 'text' }).then(c => {
    c.message.channel.overwritePermissions([
      {
        id: "@everyone",
        deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGES'],
      }
    ]);
    c.message.channel.overwritePermissions([
      {
        id: message.author.id,
        allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGES'],
      },
    ]);
```

it has something to do with the second line and the 8th line (AKA)

> c.message.channel.overwritePermissions([

X2

If I remove message from this property

> c.message.channel.overwritePermissions([

I get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'overwritePermissions' of undefined

Comment: Channel has no `message` property.

Comment: @Jakye Removing the message property gives me a new error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'overwritePermissions' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) has no `message` property, nor another `channel` property.

---

```js
message.guild.channels.create(`create-${message.author.id}`, {
    type: 'text', permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: '@everyone',
            deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL']
        },
        {
            id: message.author.id,
            allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL']
        }
    ]
})
```

---

Note that there is no permission called `READ_MESSAGES`. Instead, use `VIEW_CHANNEL`.